# Photoshop CS 2015.5 looses Object when moving

Tags: photoshop

After updating my photshop version to 2015.5, suddenly PS looses the layer-focus when trying to move an object without directly hitting it . like i have a car and a track, car is selected, but out of screen. when i try to click an drag the car but hitting the track with the mouse (because the car ist out of the screen bounds), photoshop automatically selects the track in the layer selection and i move the track not the car. it was not like that in PS 2015.

How can I stop PS from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

[image]I think you did't check [Auto select] option

- Click move tool
- It will be show auto select you can check the checkbox.

then try it I hope this helps you.

Comment: i know its the little things, but i honestly was unable to find anything about it on google. thank you :)